# Convert a array of objects to a multiple keys of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

My current array of objects looks like,

```
const data = [
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Name": "Water",
  },
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Coordinates": [
      {
        "Lat": 57.94182777439993,
        "Long": 79.50404114815193
      },
      {
        "Lat": 31.209277877460135,
        "Long": 78.80122177677728
      },
      {
        "Lat": 31.35950051982242,
        "Long": 105.15694820332524
      },
      {
        "Lat": 58.17432360099434,
        "Long": 105.42050546759074
      }
    ],
    "Name": "Water",
  },
  {
    "Type": "Location",
    "Coordinates": [
      {
        "Lat": 58.72972797827911,
        "Long": 76.90570777266291
      },
      {
        "Lat": 29.54717721331581,
        "Long": 76.37859324413196
      },
      {
        "Lat": 30.460511875130663,
        "Long": 105.19418747049103
      },
      {
        "Lat": 59.71902258556691,
        "Long": 106.7755310560839
      }
    ],
    "Name": "Water",
  }
];
```

Which need to be converted into this format,

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Water",
        "coords": [
            [57.94182777439993, 79.50404114815193],
            [31.209277877460135, 78.80122177677728],
            [31.35950051982242, 105.15694820332524],
            [58.17432360099434, 105.42050546759074]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Water",
        "coords": [
            [58.72972797827911, 76.90570777266291],
            [29.54717721331581, 76.37859324413196],
            [30.460511875130663, 105.19418747049103],
            [59.71902258556691, 106.7755310560839]
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried,

```
const output = data.reduce((accumulator, curr) => {
  if(curr.Coordinates) {
    const data = curr.Coordinates.map(({Lat, Long}) => [Lat, Long]);
    accumulator.push(data)
  };
  return accumulator;
}, []);
```

But, the code above stored my coords to a array of list.

Comment: Your desired output isn't a valid format. Those objects needs to have some sort of key

Comment: Your input is also not consistent. The last set has no name

Comment: There is no `name` property in the last entry.

Comment: @trincot Question Edited

Comment: I edited it more, as you didn't fix the output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reduce callback, just wrap the mapped coordinates in an object literal that also includes the name property:

```js
const data = [{"Type": "Location","Name": "Water",},{"Type": "Location","Coordinates": [{"Lat": 57.94182777439993,"Long": 79.50404114815193},{"Lat": 31.209277877460135,"Long": 78.80122177677728},{"Lat": 31.35950051982242,"Long": 105.15694820332524},{"Lat": 58.17432360099434,"Long": 105.42050546759074}],"Name": "Water",},{"Type": "Location","Coordinates": [{"Lat": 58.72972797827911,"Long": 76.90570777266291},{"Lat": 29.54717721331581,"Long": 76.37859324413196},{"Lat": 30.460511875130663,"Long": 105.19418747049103},{"Lat": 59.71902258556691,"Long": 106.7755310560839}],"Name": "Water",}];

const output = data.reduce((accumulator, curr) => {
  if(curr.Coordinates) {
    const Coordinates = curr.Coordinates.map(({Lat, Long}) => [Lat, Long]);
    accumulator.push({ Name: curr.Name, Coordinates});
  };
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your reduce a little bit.

Rather than pushing the coordinates array directly to the `accumulator`, make it as an `object` with `name` and `coords` as keys. Push this object to the `accumulator` to get your desired output.

```js
const data = [{"Type": "Location","Name": "Water",},{"Type": "Location","Coordinates": [{"Lat": 57.94182777439993,"Long": 79.50404114815193},{"Lat": 31.209277877460135,"Long": 78.80122177677728},{"Lat": 31.35950051982242,"Long": 105.15694820332524},{"Lat": 58.17432360099434,"Long": 105.42050546759074}],"Name": "Water",},{"Type": "Location","Coordinates": [{"Lat": 58.72972797827911,"Long": 76.90570777266291},{"Lat": 29.54717721331581,"Long": 76.37859324413196},{"Lat": 30.460511875130663,"Long": 105.19418747049103},{"Lat": 59.71902258556691,"Long": 106.7755310560839}],"Name": "Water",}];

const output = data.reduce((accumulator, curr) => {
  if (curr.Coordinates) {
    const data = {
      name: curr.Name,
      coords: curr.Coordinates.map(({ Lat, Long }) => [Lat, Long]),
    }
    accumulator.push(data)
  };
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas You are welcome, please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for.